# What is the maximum concurrency TestCafe can support

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

We are trying TestCafe with 50 concurrency and TestCafe randomly with "Cannot read property 'stackFrames' of undefined"
Same code base when we run with 20 threads works fine without any issues. Is there any upper limit on number of threads in Testcafe?
Note: - We have enough cpu to support 50 threads in aws (c5a.8xlarge)

Comment: Can you provide a more full stack trace of this exception? From there you can take a look at the repo, since the project is open source

Answer (score 2):

TestCafe has no formal limit on the number of threads. However, we have not tested the concurrency mode with so many threads. Therefore, I can only give general recommendations: make sure that you have enough resources to run so many browsers (not only CPU): RAM, disk I/O, GPU. Also, run browsers in headless mode, for example: `testcafe -c 50 chrome:headless test.js`.